# Issue with Matlab trainNetwork. What is the proper way to format observations?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning

I am trying to use a deep neural network in Matlab.  However, I get the error: Error using trainNetwork (line 165) Number of observations in X and Y disagree.

Below is my current implementation:

```
size(XX) % ans = 120000 36
size(YY) % ans = 120000 24


%% Train a Deep Neural Network
layers = [
    imageInputLayer([1 36]); % Input is an "Image" 1x36 floating point vector
    fullyConnectedLayer(200);
    reluLayer();
    fullyConnectedLayer(100);
    reluLayer();
    fullyConnectedLayer(50);
    reluLayer();
    fullyConnectedLayer(24);
    regressionLayer();
];

if ~exist(checkpoint_directory_name,'dir')
    mkdir(checkpoint_directory_name)
end

options = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
    'MaxEpochs', num_epochs, ... 
    'InitialLearnRate', 0.0001, ...
    'CheckpointPath', checkpoint_directory_name, ...
    'MiniBatchSize', batch_size ...
);

t = tic;
[net, info] = trainNetwork(XX, YY, layers, options);
fprintf('Trained in in %.02f seconds\n', toc(t));
```

What can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert regarding the deep learnig toolbox yet, however, my feeling is that the sizes should be:

```
size(XX) % answer = 36 120000;
size(YY) % answer = 24 120000;
```

Does this help?